# Basic Pandas Filtering / Cut-Paste

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm struggling with some basic pandas filtering here. All I'm trying to do is cut out all the items that contain a certain string in another column.

Here's my function:

```
df[FBPage] = df[website].where(df[website].str.contains(pat = 'facebook'))
df[website] = df[website].where(df[website].str.contains(pat = 'facebook') == False)
```

****It works when I run it once** . But then when I run it again it empties all of the FBPage column.**

Here are 3 screenshots to illustrate it's behaviour.

[Before running the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUlhu.png)
[After running once](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93PPZ.png)
[After running twice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUyqv.png)

Comment: Problem is you overwrite column `website` in part of code `df[website] = df[website].where`. Need assign to new column name, e.g. `df[noFBPage] = df[website].where`

Comment: Yes I overwrite it because to remove the non appropriate data from it.
I don't understand when my first line runs again overwrites even thought the column [website] contains no more 'facebook' in it...

Comment: Hehe I found the solution

`df[FBPage] = df[website].where(df[website].str.contains(pat = 'facebook'), df[FBPage] )`

I just needed to return the initial value if the codition isn't met

Answer (score 0):

Method `where` return missing values if not match condition, so output is expected, because os overwrite column `website`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'website':['facebook1','facebook7','no']})

#if no match facebook set NaN in FBPage column
df['FBPage'] = df['website'].where(df['website'].str.contains(pat = 'facebook'))
print (df)
     website     FBPage
0  facebook1  facebook1
1  facebook7  facebook7
2         no        NaN

#if match facebook set NaN in website column
df['website'] = df['website'].where(~df['website'].str.contains(pat = 'facebook'))
print (df)
  website     FBPage
0     NaN  facebook1
1     NaN  facebook7
2      no        NaN

#if no match facebook set NaN in FBPage column
df['FBPage'] = df['website'].where(df['website'].str.contains(pat = 'facebook', na=False))
print (df)
  website FBPage
0     NaN    NaN
1     NaN    NaN
2      no    NaN

df['website'] = df['website'].where(~df['website'].str.contains(pat = 'facebook', na=False))
print (df)
  website FBPage
0     NaN    NaN
1     NaN    NaN
2      no    NaN
```

Comment: "where return missing values if not match condition" I just understood that by continuing to test ^^ thank you.

All I had to do it to return it's inital value in case it didn't match

`df[FBPage] = df[website].where(df[website].str.contains(pat = 'facebook'), df[FBPage] )`